# Flutter : How to automatically change the page after passing a certain time?

Tags: flutter, dart, countdown

Thank you for reading my question and taking your time. I am trying to add a function that makes you go back to the home screen after a certain time passes in Flutter. I have struggled with this problem for 3 weeks so I came here.

There are 4 pages.

- HomeScreen()
- SecondRoute()
- ThirdRoute()
- ForthRoute()

When you go to the next page or SecondRoute(), a timer starts. If you go to the next page or ThirdRoute(), the timer restarts.  I succeeded in adding this timer function, but the page transition never happened after reaching 0.

### 1. My codes

---

Here are my codes below.

**mian.dart**

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:provider/provider.dart';
import 'package:question/fourth_route.dart';
import 'package:question/second_route.dart';
import 'package:question/third_route.dart';
import 'package:question/timer_store.dart';

import 'home_screen.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(ChangeNotifierProvider(
    create: (context) => TimerStore(),
    child: MyApp(),
  ));
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Question',
      theme: ThemeData.dark(),
      initialRoute: '/',
      routes: {
        '/': (context) => HomeScreen(),
        '/second_route': (context) => SecondRoute(),
        '/third_route': (context) => ThirdRoute(),
        '/fourth_route': (context) => FourthRoute(),
      },
    );
  }
}
```

**time_store.dart**

```
import 'dart:async';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

import 'home_screen.dart';

class TimerStore with ChangeNotifier {
  static const COUNTER_VALUE = 10; // TODO: ユーザーが設定できるように
  var count = COUNTER_VALUE;
  static const sec = const Duration(seconds: 1);
  static const ms = const Duration(milliseconds: 1);
  Timer _timer;

  startTimer() {
    if (_timer != null) {
      _timer.cancel();
    }

    count = COUNTER_VALUE;
    _timer = Timer.periodic(sec, (timer) {
      updateCounter();
    });
  }

  void updateCounter() {
    if (count > 0) {
      count--;
      print(count);
    } else {
      _timer.cancel();
      updateCounter2();
      updateCounter4;
    }
    notifyListeners();
  }

//追加
  void updateCounter2() {
    print('page trangition');
  }

  void updateCounter3(BuildContext context) {
    Navigator.of(context).push(MaterialPageRoute(
      builder: (context) => HomeScreen(),
    ));
  }

  void updateCounter4(BuildContext context){
    Navigator.push(
        context,
        MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => HomeScreen()));
  }



  @override
  void dispose() {
    super.dispose();
    _timer.cancel();
  }

//追加 ---
  void stopTimer() {
    _timer.cancel();
  }

  void restartTimer() {
    startTimer();
  }
}
```

### 2. Problems

---

In order to see if the function is working, I used "print" and checked the output in the console. I could see the count down and "page transition" word of updateCounter2().

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9W2Zh.png)

```
  void updateCounter() {
    if (count > 0) {
      count--;
      print(count);
    } else {
      _timer.cancel();
      updateCounter2();
      updateCounter4;
    }
    notifyListeners();
  }

//追加
  void updateCounter2() {
    print('page trangition');
  }
```

However, **updateCounter4** did not work. I know this looks strange because it should have () like updateCounter4(). But if I do that I got an error saying,

> 1 positional argument(s) expected, but 0 found.  Try adding the missing arguments.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DQMGX.png)

I know updateCounter4 needs arguments which is context. But I am not sure what exactly should be added in the() of updateCounter4...

I put "updateCounter4(context)" but it did not work...

Hope you understand my question and provide me advice. If it is not clear enough, happy to explain the details.

**Thank you so much.**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you can use Timer for that

```
 @override
void initState() {
 Timer(Duration(seconds: 3), (){
Navigator.pushReplacement(context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context)=> 
 HomeScreen()));
});
 super.initState();
}
```

this will route you to your home screen after 3 seconds

and make sure to import dart:async at the top of your file

```
import 'dart:async';
```